# RSA and AES encryption

Tags: javascript, encryption-asymmetric, encryption-symmetric, google-chrome-app

I am looking at the feasibility for using Chrome apps for the front end of some applications I am working on. (As an aside, if anyone has any thoughts on this  - put it in the comments)

I would be using `chrome.socket` and would want the connections to be secure so will need RSA and AES encryption that will be compatible with as many backend technology implementations as possible (C#, Java, ...). What I mean by this is the different modes, key-lengths, implementation-specific details...

Now I have done a little searching myself and found https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/ for AES encryption. **Is this still the accepted library to use, or is there another?**

...however, **I couldn't find a library for RSA?**

On the note of security, I don't foresee this being an issue as this is a Chrome extension,so the HTML/JavaScript is not being send over the internet, **but is there any other security implication that I have missed?**

Comment: `chrome.socket` (there is no chrome.sockets) isn't available in Chrome extensions.

Comment: OK, but `chrome.socket` still isn't available in Chrome extensions.

Comment: @sowbug Unless I am missing something obvious, I believe it is even in the `Stable` branch now: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.html

Comment: Chrome extensions can't use the socket API. Chrome apps can. There are absolutely no plans to make the socket API available to extensions.

Comment: @sowbug Thanks! Clearly I was getting muddled up!

Answer (score 5):

You could try using this:

Stanford Javascript Crypto Library: http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/

> SJCL is secure. It uses the industry-standard AES algorithm at 128, 192 or 256 bits; the SHA256 hash function; the HMAC authentication code; the PBKDF2 password strengthener; and the CCM and OCB authenticated-encryption modes.

Check the API here: http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/doc/

Stanford also has a page showing RSA (among others) encryption in Javascript: [http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/%7Etjw/jsbn/)

> RSA and ECC in JavaScript:
>
> The jsbn library is a fast, portable implementation of large-number math in pure JavaScript, enabling public-key crypto and other applications on desktop and mobile browsers.

They also state it is 100% interoperable with `openssl` and have instructions on how you can confirm this.

You could also try CryptoJS: https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/

> CryptoJS is a growing collection of standard and secure cryptographic algorithms implemented in JavaScript using best practices and patterns. They are fast, and they have a consistent and simple interface.

Comment: but the google cryptoJS does not support RSA (as partially been the question), right?

Comment: @humanityANDpeace looks like there is proposed code for this: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/crypto-js/xUdAHo7RXEg

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might prefer to have a full TLS implementation here. You should be able to wrap chrome.socket with a TLS wrapper using forge (a JavaScript implementation of TLS):

https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge

Answer (score 0):

I'm pointing out some of my work I did for university, it's probably full of bugs and could be done in a better way. It's quite fast and works well with big keys. It's possible to use RSA with keys with n Bits.

Check the tests if you need to understand how it works. Any bug or improvement would be appreciated though.

Note, you might have to search a little because there is more than just RSA.

https://github.com/llacroix/rsa-js